# Adding taxonomy terms based on custom field

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I have a custom post type that I am setting up so that different sets of custom fields are displayed based on the type of post it is. It's one of three (collection, product, or variant).

I have everything set up in that regard, but I am thinking that when designing my templates to display different data depending on the input type, it may be easier to do it if I had the input type defined as a taxonomy.

So I would like to update my post with the corresponding taxonomy that relates to the input type.

I came up with this, but it is not doing the trick.

To clarify, my taxonomy:

```
function set_tax_terms() {
    global $wpdb;
    $post_id = $wpdb->get_results ('SELECT ID FROM wp_hyhg_posts WHERE post_type = uc-collections' , object);

    foreach ($post_id as $id) {
        //get the input_type meta 
        $term= get_post_meta( $id, 'input_type', true );
        //get the term id that matches the input type
        $term_id = term_exists( $term, 'input' );
        //set the post term based on above results
        wp_set_post_terms( $id, $term_id, 'input', true ); 
    }
}

set_tax_terms();
```

Any ideas?

Based on another post, I also tried this method with no success. (I am putting this code in a snippet plugin, so I can easily activate it and deactivate.)

```
function set_tax_terms() {              
    $args = array('post_type' =>'uc-collections');                
    $post_id=get_post( $args );

    if($post_id) {
        foreach ($post_id as $id) {
            //get the input_type meta 
            $term= get_post_meta( $id->ID, 'input_type', true );
            //get the term id that matches the input type
            if(!empty($term)) {
                $term_id = term_exists( $term, 'input' );
                //set the post term based on above results
                wp_set_post_terms( $id->ID, $term_id, 'input', true ); 
            }
        }
    }
}

set_tax_terms();
```

For some reason I am not getting the code set up below to work. So I'm trying to figure out how things are related in the database.

In the term table: my term_id/ slug relationship for the items in question are : 57/ collection,  58/product, 59/ variant.

This is what I would assume would be in the term_relationships table, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I see object_id and term_taxonomy_id, one example being 3838 / 67  which corresponds to a post That I defined a term for, and the term_taxonomy table.  I am seeing that there is a term_taxonomy_id, and then term_id  as 67 / 59 which would be my variant selection.

I guess I'm not sure why there are two different numbers in this case.  I don't know why this doesn't want to work. Guess I'm going do it manually.

Comment: Are you trying to set the terms from meta on post save? What the application for setting your terms?

Comment: well I already have all the post defined, so I dont want to go through 700+ entries to define the taxonomy, I just need to update it with a query. 

I don't understand your second question.

Comment: What form are you storing the term in meta as? Is it the term_id or slug? Because if it's one of those two, you can avoid the `term_exists()` call which hits the database each time. Working on an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just the following:

Just a couple of things to note:

- By using `get_term_by()` instead of `term_exists()`, you hit the term cache instead of the database for every retrieval of the term object.

```php
/**
 * Set terms for the given post type based on a meta value.
 */
function wpdocs_set_terms_for_post_types() {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'uc-collections',
    ) );

    if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            if ( $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'input_type', true ) {
                if ( is_string( $meta ) && $term = get_term_by( 'slug', strtolower( $meta ) ) ) {
                    wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID, $term->slug, 'input' );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
wpdocs_set_terms_for_post_types();
```

Comment: well im still not 100% sure if I'm understanding the term id in meta. I set the term id because the codex says that if you have heretical taxonomies, you need a term id. 

one row of data would look like this meta_id, post_id= 3311, meta_key= input_type, meta_value= variant.

Im not sure if it makes a difference if my taxonomies are heiretical or not. but I did set them as such, hence the code above.  collection> product> variant

Comment: I need you to be more specific. You're storing a value in a meta key called 'input_type'. What are you storing there? Is it a term slug, is it a term ID. What is it?

Comment: and sorry, i submitted the comment too early

Comment: and I only have one post type I am editing.  uc-collections

Comment: The problem is that in order to set a term using a meta value, you need to store something in that meta value that directly correlates to an existing term. So if the term slug is 'collections' and you store it in meta, you can retrieve it, use that value to retrieve the term object and assign that object to the post. So in order to help you, I need to know what value(s) you're storing using the meta key 'input_type'.

Comment: perhaps.  basically my input_type values are either collection, product, or variant.  and are stored as such in the database. My taxonomy terms are also collection, product, or variant. So i just need to assign the proper taxonomy term based on whatever the the input_type value is.

Comment: Great. I've adjusted the example to work for your use case.

Comment: didnt work unfortunately. can you explain why you are including the Get_term_by function in the if statement?  Perhaps we can try it without the ID and use slug instead. I'm not sure. I can make the taxonomy non hierarchical if you think it could help

Comment: The function uses the term slug currently already. One final thing you can try is changing 'slug' to 'name' in this line:
`&& $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $meta, 'input' )`.
Beyond that, I don't know how else I can help you. I've tested this code and it works.

Comment: Alright, i'll play with it some more. I dont know what is going on with it. Thanks for trying. If it doesnt work, i guess ill just be updating things manually, like every other thing ive had to do. This site is turning into a pain.

Comment: would capitilization make a difference? cause if i just echo the results of the meta data, i notice some are capitalized most are not

Comment: As long as the word stored in the meta key exactly matches the slug for the term, regardless of capitalization, you can just change `get_term_by( 'slug', $meta, 'input' )` to `get_term_by( 'slug', strtolower( $meta ), 'input' )`.

Comment: Ok, I put moved the term line outside of the if statement and echoed it, and no results are displaying for the term value, which would explain why the post are not updating. 

  $term = get_term_by( 'slug', strtolower( $meta ), 'input' );
            
            echo "meta:".$meta . "- term: " .$term. " ";

the results look like this: meta:Variant- term: meta:Product- term: meta:variant- term: